# Copy 1 file to another file, but I have path for both the files in 1 folder

Tags: ant

```
<copy file="${fnd0_tcSSStagingLocation}\login/login_webapp_root\WEB-INF\classes\logl4j2.xml.template" tofile="${fnd0_tcSSStagingLocation}\login/login_webapp_root\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml" overwrite="true"/>
```

I have wrote this code this does not have any issue but it not copying logl4j2.xml.template into logl4j2.xml

Comment: You have a combination of "/" and "\" in your file paths. Ant can usually deal with this, but you should probably make this consistent. I recommend first setting each file to a property using the `property` task with its `location` attribute (instead of `value`) so that Ant will cast the values to canonical paths. As for your main issue, there's a good chance it's because the file doesn't exist in the specified location. Please verify that it's actually there.